# Не удаляется папка

Tags: java, android, файлы

Когда я выхожу из приложения  должна удаляться папка в которой работал пользователь. Она удаляется только в том случае   если в папке нет других папок, в противном она не удаляется и `file.delete` выдает `false`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    File file = new File(folder.getPath(), folder.getName());
    boolean result=file.delete(); 
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Содержание `folder`

```
String date= DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
folder.setName(date);
folder.setPath(getFilesDir());
```

Создание доп.папок

```
String number=edNumber.getText().toString();
File file=new File(folder.getPath()+"/"+folder.getName(),number);
boolean result=file.mkdir();
```

Конечно есть решение удалять основную папку после удаления всех других папок в ней через for, но очень сильно бы хотелось узреть другое решение этой проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory);
```

Этот метод доступен в том же file. Это также рекурсивно удаляет все подпапки и файлы под ними.

Docs: [org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File))

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195797/delete-all-files-in-directory-but-not-directory-one-liner-solution

Comment: Спасибо, работает.